# Maximum sum in a rank-ordered list

Tags: arrays, math

I know it's not a programming question but it involves programming and some math.
Say I have a set of **N** items, all have their points, and ordered by their ranks. For example:

```
list1 = { // N = 4
1: (item1, points: 100, rank:1), 
2: (item2, points:55, rank:2), 
3: (item3, points:55, rank:2),
4: (item4, points:45, rank:3) }
```

and so on. list2 is another list of these 4 (N) items, but with different points, thus different ranks. I'm trying to do a comparison for these two lists, like the sum of the differences of item ranks in two lists.

For example:

```
list2 = { // N = 4
1: (item4, points: 10, rank:1), 
2: (item3, points:9, rank:2), 
3: (item2, points:8, rank:3),
4: (item1, points:7, rank:4) }
```

in this case the sum of differences S = (item1 rank difference + item2 " " + ....)
S= 3 + 1 + 0 + 2 = 6

in order to compare it with the worst case, I need this sum's worst value for different N's.

so, what is the maximum value of S in terms of N?
S_max (N) =?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand, but the worst value for 2 lists of length N would be every item in list 1 is ranked 1 and no item in list 2 share the same rank (not the sole worst case, but definitively a worst case) :

```
sum = (1-1)+(2-1)+...+((n-1)-1)+(n-1)
    =  0 + 1 + ... + (n-2) + (n-1)
    = n(n-1)/2
```

Comment: If all items in list 1 have rank 1 and all items in list 2 have rank n, the sum of differences would be n(n-1), no?

Comment: In a ranking it is not possible to have items with  the same rank with rank > 1 (you have to have at least one first, at least one second, and so on)